# User cannot move Folder A1 from within Folder A to Folder B, but CAN move Folder A2, despite having the same permissions to both folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-permissions

A user with "Edit" access to a document library is unable to use the "Move To" button to move a folder "Folder A1" from within "Folder A" to "Folder B". The error message they see is simply "Access Denied".

- All of these folders are in the same document library, and are
  inheriting permissions.
- No item in any of these folders has unique permissions.
- No documents are checked out, and all documents have a checked in
  version.
- This user is able to move other folders, such as "Folder A2" in
  "Folder A" to "Folder B" with no problems.
- If I move the folder with my Sharepoint Administrator permissions it
  moves without issue.
- Content approval for submitted items is disabled, and documents do
  not need to be checked out before editing.

I can't think of anything else to check, have I missed anything obvious or simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that finds this in the future the fix was to remove the user's permission completely and then re-add it at the top level.

Comment: As sceptical as I was about this answer, it did actually work for me.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check as following:

1. Clear the browser cache, sign out and sign in agian to compare the
   results.
2. Create a new folder named FolderA3 within Folder A, upload test documents to it, check if you could move the new folder to FolderB.
3. Check if you could use **Copy to** normally.
4. Remove the user permission in this library and grant again to check if the issue still exists.

Comment: Thanks for your response.